# Formal word for overhyped?

Tags: single-word-requests, formality

Is there a formal word for overhyped?
(using the definition: make exaggerated claims about (a product, idea, or event); publicize or promote excessively.)

Comment: I wouldn't say that "overhyped" was particularly informal.

Comment: But only Uber can *uberhype.*

Comment: Yeah. The word is ADVERTISING! (I'm being facetious--kinda.) Don

Comment: Welcome to SE EL&U. One of the things we require in questions asking for a word is an example sentence of usage. Otherwise I might have said "exaggerated", which you use in your sentence would do. It will do in a sentence "the claims for this product are ...........", but not for "this product is ...........". Which is it, or do you not care?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Overhyped* might strike you as informal simply because it's relatively new. The first citation in the OED is from 1979 for the verb and 1980 for the adjective. I can see how *overhyped* could seem like an unusual word choice to refer to something that isn't relatively modern. If you are looking for another word that's used in settings in addition to advertising and may be more appropriate, I suggest

**inflated** (adj.)

> Elaborated or heightened by artificial or empty means
>
> *an inflated style of writing* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inflated)

> 2. pompous; bombastic; high-flown
> 3. increased or raised beyond what is normal or valid [Webster’s New World College Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/inflated)

> Englarged beyond truth or reasonableness [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/inflated)

---

> Technologies tend to get **overhyped (inflated expectations)**
> after their initial introduction to the market. [G. Grant and R.
> Collins; *The Value Imperative*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Value_Imperative/4t56DAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=overhyped%20inflated&pg=PA8&printsec=frontcover)

> ... the desperation for a 'miracle recovery' so common in fiction or
> media reportage is shared by the loved ones of the patient, leading to
> 'costs of **inflated promise**', an **over-hyped assurance** that is
> further communicated and perpetuated in the press. [Matthew Colbeck;
> *The Language and Imagery of Brain Injury*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Language_and_Imagery_of_Coma_and_Bra/dqIjEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=over-hyped%20inflated&pg=PA186&printsec=frontcover)

> ...Consumers' Research Incorporated which reported on competing
> products' quality and value and sought particularly to prick the
> bubble of **inflated advertising claims**. [M. Bevir and F. Trentmann;
> *Critiques of Capital in Modern Britain and America*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Critiques_of_Capital_in_Modern_Britain_a/CX-HDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=inflated%20advertising%20claims&pg=PA128&printsec=frontcover)

> The second approach meant advertising poor quality products in a
> flashy manner ('hucksterism') and treating consumers as 'gullible
> dupes' who would be convinced by **inflated product claims**.
> [Caroline Koegler; *Critical Branding*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Critical_Branding/3f5QDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22inflated%20product%22&pg=PT178&printsec=frontcover)

> Such criticisms might be seen as having a primarily anecdotal value,
> merely adding to the commercial overkill of a **media-inflated
> event**. [Graham Huggan; *The Post-Colonial Exotic: Marketing the
> Margins*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Postcolonial_Exotic/y6WBAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22inflated%20event%22&pg=PA109&printsec=frontcover)

> The other conflict that will not be found in this volume is an action
> grandiloquently or facetiously known as “The Lowell War.” This
> **inflated event** occurred on November 21, 1857, at the town named in the title. [Le Roy Barnett; *Michigan's Early Military Forces*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Michigan_s_Early_Military_Forces/LPPdAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22inflated%20event%22&pg=PA12&printsec=frontcover)

> When experiments have used these methods, their findings have
> indicated that when advertisements that **inflate the product
> performance** of a consumer product are made, the participants reported
> a higher level of intent to buy the product. [David Hill;
> *Encyclopedia of Deception, vol. 2*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Encyclopedia_of_Deception/iRJzAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22inflate%20the%20product%22&pg=PA13&printsec=frontcover)
>
> Packaging may be cleverly designed to give an **inflated impression**
> of quality. [K. Brumfitt et al.; *Marketing*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Marketing/EO68sPDwjUIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=inflated%20advertising%20claims&pg=PA63&printsec=frontcover)

> But I consider that the particular illustrative example used here will
> give the non-statistician a grossly **inflated idea** of the power of
> the moving average to give useful information. [*Journal of the South
> African Institute of Mining and Metallurgy*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=inflated%20idea)

> Both Klein's and Manzoni's oeuvres featured Conceptualism's irony.  Klein's exhibition of literally invisible “paintings” (the “zones of
> immaterial pictorial sensitivity”) foreshadowed many Conceptual works
> that carried the **inflated idea** of the “last painting” ad absurdum.
> [Thomas McEvilley; *Capacity*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Capacity/srvsCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=inflated%20idea%20advertising&pg=PT98&printsec=frontcover)